# Changing Dragablz header color?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve here is to change the white of the header text. (Dialogs, Mahapps, Palette) to something else and also the green below Dialogs. I tried changing the white to black using foreground property but that didn't do anything.

```
 <dragablz:TabablzControl  FixedHeaderCount="3" >
        <TabItem Foreground="Black" Header="DIALOGS">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Hello World</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="MATERIAL">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Material Design</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="PALETTE">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Looks Quite Nice</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
    </dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Live Visual Tree, and checked where the current foreground color is coming from? You could also just try to set the `Foreground` property of the `TextBlock` directly instead of setting the `Foreground` property of the `TabItem` (this should override any other colors that may be set by a style).

Comment: The textblock is inside the tab, just like a button. How is that going to change the header color as well? I will take a look at the visual tree.

Comment: Ah I misread that.. Sorry, but looking at the Visual Tree might still help finding out where the color is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your "own" `TextBlock` element to the `Header` of the `TabItem`, and there set the `Foreground` brush (and override any styles that might otherwise affect it) like this:

```
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="DIALOGS" Foreground="Black" />
        </TabItem.Header>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Hello World</TextBlock>
    </TabItem>
```